# How do you get the next div to trigger for Scroll Follow?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Not sure what I am doing wrong or what I am missing from my code but I am using http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

The issue is the first one works and scrolls to the appropriate height but the second one does not move. How do I find out when the top one ends and how to trigger the second one underneath it? (I am no javascript expert and couldn't seem to find any info on how to resolve the issue)

```
<div id="container-tag">
    <div class="tag-cloud" id="cloud" style="top: 0px;">  
       <a rel="tag" href="http://elkartel.com/tag/turrets">Turrets</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
             jQuery('#cloud').scrollFollow();                               

    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the first one works" and "the second one does not move"? What is the first one, what the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just run the scrollFollow function on a containing element?
That way the whole thing will follow the scrolling as 1.

ie:

```
$('#container-tag').scrollFollow();
```